# Навести указатель мыши в pywinauto на элемент, не поддерживающий click()

Tags: python, pywinauto

Всем привет. Подскажите, есть ли возможность в pywinaouto получить координаты rectangle() и записать их в переменные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить координаты курсора - даже не в pywinauto, а в пакете pywin32, от которого pywinauto зависит:

```
import win32gui
(x, y) = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
```

А если нужна середина элемента, то

```
app.MainWindow.OKButton.rectangle().mid_point()
# возвращает объект класса POINT с полями x и y
```

Сделать натуральный клик на середину элемента:

```
app.MainWindow.OKButton.click_input()
```

При желании можно кликать не в середину, передав параметры `coords=(x, y)` и `absolute=False`.

Comment: Василий, спасибо огромное!

Comment: А можете еще подсказать, почему операции с найденными элементами для некоторых приложений выполняются так долго? Например после того как элемент найден, клик по нему выполняется через 9-15 секунд.
Отслеживаю дебагом- поиск выполняется очень быстро, а вот на самой операции 15 секунд

```search_bar = main_window.child_window(class_name='RadDocking', auto_id='Docking', title='Rad Docking')\
    .child_window(auto_id='SearchPane', class_name='RadPane').child_window(class_name='SearchView')\
    .child_window(auto_id="FullNameBox", class_name='RadWatermarkTextBox')
search_bar.click_input()```

Comment: Опубликовал отдельным вопросом здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1449722/%d0%92-pywinauto-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb