# В PywinAuto операции с объектами интерфейса некоторых приложений выполняются долго (15-20 секунд). Как можно оптимизировать это?

Tags: python, pywinauto

Всем привет. Может кто сталкивался. Помогите опитимизировать.
В PywinAuto операции с найденными элементами для некоторых приложений выполняются достаточно долго. Например, после того как элемент найден, click_input() по нему выполняется через 9-15 секунд. Отслеживаю дебагом - поиск выполняется достаточно быстро (менее секунды), а вот на самой операции 15-20 секунд. Причем не важно какая операция. Еще пример, операция type_keys(), сама печать - все быстро, а вот перед началом операции печати пауза 15 сек

Приложение desktop карта. При просмотре с помощью inspector элементов приложения достаточно много. Может с этим связано? Есть какие-то варианты оптимизации? Заранее спасибо

Пример кода

`search_bar = main_window.child_window(auto_id="FullNameBox", class_name='RadWatermarkTextBox') search_bar.click_input()`

Comment: Отчасти разобрался в причинах. У меня действительно очень много объектов в окне и когда открываю другое представление, где объектов меньше, операции с ними выполняются существенно быстрее. Вопрос по поводу возможных вариантов оптимизации пока актуален :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что первая строка ещё не выполняет поиск, а только создаёт поисковый объект. Поиск неявно вызывается при попытке вызвать метод `click_input`. Чтобы вызвать явно поиск, нужен метод `.wrapper_object()` или `.wait('ready', timeout=10)`. Например:

```
search_bar = main_window.child_window(auto_id="FullNameBox", class_name='RadWatermarkTextBox').wrapper_object()
search_bar.click_input()
```

Причём `main_window` - скорее всего тоже поисковый объект (типа `WindowSpecification`), и по нему поиск запускается в первую очередь. Правда, текущая реализация не позволяет создавать `WindowSpecification` от враппера. Попозже сделаем в следующем большом релизе. Есть разные трюки, чтобы оптимизировать поиск:

1. Не использовать доступ по атрибуту, а юзать только `child_window(...)`
2. Юзать чаще `class_name` или `control_type` (для `backend="uia"`), потому что предварительная фильтрация по типу контрола сильно быстрее, чем по тексту. Если текст есть в критерии, то по нему поиск будет в последнюю очередь, то есть уже среди мЕньшего числа элементов. Получение текста - самая дорогая операция.
3. Можно ещё ограничивать поиск в глубину параметром `depth=1`, но тогда надо больше уровней поиска делать.

Comment: Метод `.dump_tree()` тоже пока доступен только для объектов типа `WindowSpecification`. Мы его оптимизировали, но это попадёт тоже в следующий большой релиз.

Comment: Василий спасибо большое за развернутый ответ и за Крутой инструмент pywinauto. Сейчас на его основе строю автоматизацию тестирования GUI на проекте